# Long installer startup time - add dialog before wpWelcome?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

My Installer created with Inno Setup is about 850 MB in size containing about 7000 files and 890 Folders to an uncompressed size of 1.98 GB.

When starting the install process, after the *Windows UAC Dialog* shows up, the Installer is sitting with an empty icon in the *Taskbar* for approx. 45 seconds before the *Welcome Dialog* is being shown.

I'm assuming that this is happening during the process of unpacking the installer? Running the installer with just a dummy file entry has the *Welcome Dialog* show up immediately.

In the `[Files]` section, I only specify a single relative folder:

```
Source: "{#Source}\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
```

Compression in the `[Setup]` section is set to:

```
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes
```

Is there a dialog I can show during that time that gives the user visual feedback that something is being prepared?

---

To append to this question:
The last entry in the Log file before the 45 second hang is:

```
Extracting temporary file: C:\Users\Markus\AppData\Local\Temp\is-CBETM.tmp\license.rtf
```

I'm using a custom License Page on which I extract the file and load it as RTFText:

```pascal
procedure LicensePage_Create;
var
    LicenseFileName: string;
    LicenseFilePath: string;
    LicenseText: AnsiString;

begin
    LicensePage := CreateOutputMsgMemoPage(wpSelectDir, SetupMessage(msgWizardLicense), SetupMessage(msgLicenseLabel), SetupMessage(msgLicenseLabel3), '');
    LicensePage.RichEditViewer.Height := WizardForm.LicenseMemo.Height;
    LicenseFileName := 'license.rtf';
    ExtractTemporaryFile(LicenseFileName);
    LicenseFilePath := ExpandConstant('{tmp}\license.rtf');
    LoadStringFromFile(LicenseFilePath, LicenseText);
    LicensePage.RichEditViewer.RTFText := LicenseText;
    DeleteFile(LicenseFilePath);

    LicensePage.OnActivate := @LicensePageActivate;

    LicenseAcceptedRadio := CloneLicenseRadioButton(WizardForm.LicenseAcceptedRadio);
    LicenseNotAcceptedRadio := CloneLicenseRadioButton(WizardForm.LicenseNotAcceptedRadio);
    LicenseNotAcceptedRadio.Checked := True;

    LicensePageID := LicensePage.ID;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to use [`SolidCompression`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_solidcompression) (is it really worth it?), you have to put all files that are needed for the installer to start (like "license" file) **before** the big files.

Otherwise the installer has to decompress all the big files while starting.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about SolidCompression! Turning it off only adds an extra 30MB.